# sql get get first character, trim till period, then remaining characters

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a column of names and I need to select the first character till a period then get the remaining characters.

Example

Source Column name              Desired output

```
bob.smith                       bsmith
mary.alice                      malice
bill.gates                      bgates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CHARINDEX` will allow you to search for the location of the period, you can then use `SUBSTRING` to return the data you need.

Sample Data;

```
CREATE TABLE #TempData (FieldName varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #TempData (FieldName)
VALUES
('bob.smith')
,('mary.alice')
,('bill.gates')
```

Query

```
SELECT 
FieldName
,SUBSTRING(FieldName,1,1) + SUBSTRING(FieldName,CHARINDEX('.',FieldName)+1,LEN(FieldName)-CHARINDEX('.',FieldName)) Result
FROM #TempData
```

Result

```
FieldName   Result
bob.smith   bsmith
mary.alice  malice
bill.gates  bgates
```